# Get the Directory of $(ProjectDir) in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In `vcproj` Property, there exists a list of build macro properties. Among them are `$(OutDir)`, `$(ProjectName)` and `$(ProjectDir)`.

Question, what is the macro ( or the command to get the directory of `$(ProjectDir)`?

This is because I want to write the output dll to the parent directory of `$(ProjectDir)`, or a folder inside the parent folder.

Comment: what do you mean with 'get the directory of $(ProjectDir)' ?? you can jusr set the output path to $(ProjectDir), is that what you're after?

Comment: Nope, I want to set the output path to the parent directory of `($ProjectDir)`.

Answer (score 1):

simply set `Settings->General->Output Directory` ( == OutputDirectory element under  section in the vcproj file) to `$(ProjectDir)..`

alternatively if you want just the executable there, not the pdb etc, change the `General->OutputFile` to `$(ProjectDir)..\$(TargetFileName)`

edit: since this doesn't seeem to work for you, but it does for me, maybe you're missing a slash? Can you post the value of your `$(ProjectDir)`?

for example, I have these macro values in a dll project:

```
$(ProjectDir) d:\path\to\project\core\
$(ProjectPath) d:\path\to\project\core\core.vcproj
```

consequently, setting the OutputDirectory to `$(ProjectDir)..\xxx`, my dll goes here: `d:\path\to\project\core.dll`

Comment: This is not the correct answer; if you do this, then the dll will be outputted to the `$(ProjectDir)`, not the parent folder ( or a folder inside the parent folder).

Comment: This worked for me `$(ProjectDir)..\FolderInParent\SubFolder`. Thanks @stijn